# Attribute empty after assigning

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, scope, synchronous

I'm trying to refactor an object into an array to fit an API that I have to use.

```
function buildObject(data) {
    console.log(data) // correct ouput
    var jsonLayers = Object.entries({...data}).map(([k, v]) => {
        console.log(`value : ${v}`) // correct output
        return {
            label: k,
            pointMap: v,
            color: v.layerColor?v.layerColor:tabList[tabList.map(i => i.tabName).indexOf(k)].layerColor?tabList[tabList.map(i => i.tabName).indexOf(k)].layerColor:defaultPOILayerColor,
        }}
    )

    console.log(jsonLayers) // incorrect output
    return jsonLayers
}
```

I have 2 scenarios in which I call this function but with the same data (`console.log(data)` logs the exact same result).
In the first scenario I obtain the desired result and in the second the pointMap attribute is an empty Array.

In the case where it does not work the `` console.log(`value : ${v}`) `` logs the correct value but when I log `console.log(jsonLayers)` the attribute pointMap is empty.

Any ideas on why this happens ?

**Edit**: as mentionned below this code works with sample data so I suppose this must comes to how the function is called. Everything runs in a UWA widget with jQuery

So for the context here is an idea of how they are called in both cases :

```
var data = {
    a: { tabName: "tab1", layerColor: 1 },
    b: { tabName: "tab2", layerColor: 2 },
};

$('#button1').on('click', function() {
    ExternalAPI.Publish('some-external-address', buildObject(data));
});

$('#button2').on('click', function() {
    let jsonData = buildObject(data);
    //some manipulations of jsonData
    ExternalAPI.Publish('some-external-address', jsonData);
});
```

It works on button1 but not on button2, they are clicked are at a different moment but data contains the same object when both are clicked

**Edit2 :**

**Found the issue,
In the manipulations of jsonData I accidentally use slice(1,1) instead of splice(1,1) which empties the array.**

**What drove me crazy is that this modification was perform after the log but the var was log with the modification.**

**At least I learnt that spread operator does not deepcopy**

Comment: don't you think that it might be a great thing to put the inputs you are using to test this function on the question?

Comment: ```const data = {
  a: { tabName: "tab1", layerColor: 1 },
  b: { tabName: "tab2", layerColor: 2 },
};
function buildObject(data) {
  var jsonLayers = Object.entries({ ...data }).map(([k, v]) => {
    return { label: k, pointMap: v, color: v.layerColor };
  });
  console.log(jsonLayers);
  return jsonLayers;
}
buildObject(data);

``` It works with sample data.

Comment: Just guessing but the ... spread operator doesn't do a deep copy, are you maybe mutating the output jsonLayers between the two calls and this is affecting the input data object. Please can you try to reduce your example to the minimum that shows a problem?

Comment: I tried to replicate the context of the problem, I'll try to deep copy with JSON

Comment: @Maxence Fiorina, if you are trying to clone with `{...data}`, you are wrong , It only does shallow copy, And what is `tabList` ? And what is your expected output ?

Comment: Found the issue thanks, good to know the spread operator does not deepcopy

Answer (score 0):

Found the issue,

In the manipulations of jsonData I accidentally use slice(1,1) instead of splice(1,1) which empties the array.

What drove me crazy is that this modification was perform after the log but the var was log with the modification